# postgresql: jsonb implementation details?

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to understand what is the implementation detail of `jsonb` in postgresql. I could not find it at:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-json.html

or doing similar search. What is the low level implementation of `jsonb` in postgresql ?

1. [bson](http://bsonspec.org/) ?
2. [bjson](http://bjson.org/) ?
3. [ubjson](https://ubjson.org/) ?

Comment: The source cod is [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/backend/utils/adt)  and [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/utils/jsonb.h) - I think it's none of those you listed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a_horse_with_no_name, I could review quickly the code. Turns out this is a specific implementation for postgresql:

- https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/d9134d0a355cfa447adc80db4505d5931084278a